# iterate over firestore array field with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array field in a firestore document like so:
[image]

Assuming that I have already gotten the DocumentReference which contains this field via:

```
var myref = db.collection("foo").doc("bar");
```

How would I iterate over each string in the array?

Comment: You should provide a clear scenario and the issue you are facing and also what exactly do you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do as follows:

```
var docRef = db.collection("foo").doc("bar");

docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        const emergencyContacts = doc.data().EmergencyContacts;
        for (var key in emergencyContacts) {
          console.log(emergencyContacts[key]);
        }
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

---

`doc.data()` returns all fields in the document as an Object, and since the field `EmergencyContacts` is of type [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), you need to loop over the Array.

`const emergencyContacts = doc.get("EmergencyContacts");` also works, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#get).

Answer (score -1):

You can try by first getting reference of a document having all the data and then loop through it.
Something like following:

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        doc.data().EmergencyContacts.forEach(data => console.log("data", data));
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Comment: doesn't doc.data() in this case return the entire contents of the document? I don't want to loop through the document, I want to iterate through the contents of a field in the document

Comment: Yes, i think you just need to get the data first in order to iterate over them. i had the same situation in my project and this approach worked fine. @Cease
for more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data